# How do i merge cells together in an xsl file stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have been told to merge all the common names of bus stops which appear in the same location, e.g `Aberdeen` has three common stops, but they are in separate cells. How would I combine these so that all the common stops would appear under one locality `Aberdeen` in my XSL-stylesheet?

Below is my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>BusStops</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Locality</th>
        <th>BusStop</th>
        <th> Co-ordinates </th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="BusStops/BusStopDetails">
      <xsl:sort select="LocalityName"/>     
      <tr>  
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="LocalityName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="ParentLocalityName"/>) </td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="CommonName"/></td>
        <td>
             <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;q={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">
             (<xsl:value-of select="Latitude"/>) , (<xsl:value-of select="Longitude"/>)
            </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my XML sample:

```
<BusStopDetails>
    <AtcoCode>639070021
    </AtcoCode> 
    <CommonName>Union Square Bus Station
    </CommonName>
    <LocalityName>Aberdeen
    </LocalityName>
    <ParentLocalityName/>
    <Latitude>57.1445763077
    </Latitude>
    <Longitude>-2.0963111958
    </Longitude>
</BusStopDetails>

<BusStopDetails>
    <AtcoCode>639080008
    </AtcoCode>
    <CommonName>Aberdeen Railway Station
    </CommonName>
    <LocalityName>Aberdeen
    </LocalityName>
    <ParentLocalityName/>
    <Latitude>57.1437934462
    </Latitude>
    <Longitude>-2.0980112638
    </Longitude>
</BusStopDetails>

-<BusStopDetails>
    <AtcoCode>9300ABA
    </AtcoCode>
    <CommonName>Aberdeen Ferry Terminal
    </CommonName>
    <LocalityName>Aberdeen
    </LocalityName>
    <ParentLocalityName/>
    <Latitude>57.1447953603
    </Latitude>
    <Longitude>-2.0917010936
    </Longitude>
</BusStopDetails>
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of your desired output?

Comment: Yeah i shall edit it just now @DanielHaley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example that also uses `xsl:key`...

**XML Input** (added another `BusStopDetails` for a better example)

```
<BusStops>
    <BusStopDetails>
        <AtcoCode>639070021</AtcoCode>
        <CommonName>Some common name</CommonName>
        <LocalityName>Stackoverflow</LocalityName>
        <ParentLocalityName>Some Parent Loc</ParentLocalityName>
        <Latitude>57.1445763077</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-2.0963111958</Longitude>
    </BusStopDetails>
    <BusStopDetails>
        <AtcoCode>639070021</AtcoCode>
        <CommonName>Union Square Bus Station</CommonName>
        <LocalityName>Aberdeen</LocalityName>
        <ParentLocalityName/>
        <Latitude>57.1445763077</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-2.0963111958</Longitude>
    </BusStopDetails>
    <BusStopDetails>
        <AtcoCode>639080008</AtcoCode>
        <CommonName>Aberdeen Railway Station</CommonName>
        <LocalityName>Aberdeen
        </LocalityName>
        <ParentLocalityName/>
        <Latitude>57.1437934462</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-2.0980112638</Longitude>
    </BusStopDetails>
    <BusStopDetails>
        <AtcoCode>9300ABA</AtcoCode>
        <CommonName>Aberdeen Ferry Terminal</CommonName>
        <LocalityName>Aberdeen    </LocalityName>
        <ParentLocalityName/>
        <Latitude>57.1447953603</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-2.0917010936</Longitude>
    </BusStopDetails>
</BusStops>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="detailsByLocality" match="BusStopDetails" use="normalize-space(LocalityName)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/BusStops">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>BusStops</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Locality</th>
            <th>BusStop</th>
            <th>Co-ordinates</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="BusStopDetails[count(.|key('detailsByLocality',normalize-space(LocalityName))[1])=1]">
            <xsl:sort select="LocalityName"/>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="{count(key('detailsByLocality',normalize-space(LocalityName))) + 1}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(LocalityName)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ParentLocalityName"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('detailsByLocality',normalize-space(LocalityName))"/>
          </xsl:for-each>          
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BusStopDetails">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(CommonName)"/></td>
      <td>
        <a
          href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;q={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',Latitude,' , ',Longitude,')')"/>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ParentLocalityName[string()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' (',normalize-space(),')')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>BusStops</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Locality</th>
            <th>BusStop</th>
            <th>Co-ordinates</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Aberdeen</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Union Square Bus Station</td>
            <td><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=57.1445763077,-2.0963111958&amp;q=57.1445763077,-2.0963111958&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">(57.1445763077 , -2.0963111958)</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Aberdeen Railway Station</td>
            <td><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=57.1437934462,-2.0980112638&amp;q=57.1437934462,-2.0980112638&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">(57.1437934462 , -2.0980112638)</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Aberdeen Ferry Terminal</td>
            <td><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=57.1447953603,-2.0917010936&amp;q=57.1447953603,-2.0917010936&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">(57.1447953603 , -2.0917010936)</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Stackoverflow (Some Parent Loc)</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Some common name</td>
            <td><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=57.1445763077,-2.0963111958&amp;q=57.1445763077,-2.0963111958&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">(57.1445763077 , -2.0963111958)</a></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ3916)</kbd>

Comment: @TurtleDave - You're welcome. If this answer is sufficient, please accept it by clicking the check mark (✅) next to it.

Comment: @DaneilHaley Hello, i was wondering if you could possibly explain how exactly the rowspan works??

Comment: @TurtleDave - Maybe this will help: http://www.html5-tutorials.org/tables/colspan-rowspan/

Comment: @TurtleDave - Why did you unaccept my answer? Is something wrong with it? If so, I'll be happy to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following stylesheet. I haven't modified your formatting, I merely adjusted the layout of the templates. You should probably replace `/root` in the first template with `BusStops` or something like this. I cannot elaborate on this because you did not provide a full XML file. But this will be trivial for you. I also replaced the sorted `for-each` with a sorted `apply-templates`. It works well. If you don't like the result to be sorted by `CommonName` but rather by `LocalityName`, replace it. Or add a second layer that sorts first by `CommonName` and then by `LocalityName`. This solution should be instructive.

The **XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="a.xslt"?>
<root>
<BusStopDetails>
    <AtcoCode>639070021
    </AtcoCode> 
    <CommonName>Union Square Bus Station
    </CommonName>
    <LocalityName>Aberdeen
    </LocalityName>
    <ParentLocalityName/>
    <Latitude>57.1445763077
    </Latitude>
    <Longitude>-2.0963111958
    </Longitude>
</BusStopDetails>

<BusStopDetails>
    <AtcoCode>639080008
    </AtcoCode>
    <CommonName>Aberdeen Railway Station
    </CommonName>
    <LocalityName>Aberdeen
    </LocalityName>
    <ParentLocalityName/>
    <Latitude>57.1437934462
    </Latitude>
    <Longitude>-2.0980112638
    </Longitude>
</BusStopDetails>

-<BusStopDetails>
    <AtcoCode>9300ABA
    </AtcoCode>
    <CommonName>Aberdeen Ferry Terminal
    </CommonName>
    <LocalityName>Aberdeen
    </LocalityName>
    <ParentLocalityName/>
    <Latitude>57.1447953603
    </Latitude>
    <Longitude>-2.0917010936
    </Longitude>
</BusStopDetails>
</root>
```

The **XSLT file**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>BusStops</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Locality</th>
            <th>BusStop</th>
            <th>Coordinates </th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="BusStopDetails">
            <xsl:sort select="LocalityName" order="ascending" />
            <xsl:sort select="CommonName" order="ascending" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BusStopDetails">   <!-- in your setup you may use 'BusStops/BusStopDetails' --> 
    <tr>  
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="LocalityName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="ParentLocalityName"/>) </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="CommonName"/></td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;q={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">
          (<xsl:value-of select="Latitude"/>) , (<xsl:value-of select="Longitude"/>)
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Logiee: I updated my answer. Now it should sort first by `LocalityName` and second by `CommonName`. My test worked. I simply removed the check for the name 'Aberdeen'  and generalized it. Hope this helps.

Comment: i have provided a sample of what it should look like

Answer (score 0):

Here a straightforward XSL 1.0 solution/idea using for-each and key.
1. Generate a key:

```
<xsl:key  name="kLocalityName" match="BusStopDetails" use="LocalityName"/>
```

2 iterate over the group:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="BusStopDetails[generate-id() = 
                                generate-id(key('kLocalityName', LocalityName)[1])]"  >
```

3. iterate over each group member:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="key('kLocalityName', $this)" >
   ```

Update
Try  this (without html output - because I do not how it should lock like)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:key  name="kLocalityName" match="BusStopDetails" use="LocalityName"/>
        <xsl:template match="/*">
                        <!--for-each select="BusStops/BusStopDetails" group >-->
                        <xsl:for-each select="BusStopDetails[generate-id() = 
                                                                            generate-id(key('kLocalityName', LocalityName)[1])]"  >

                            <xsl:sort select="LocalityName"/>
                            <BusStopGroup>
                                <gname>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="LocalityName"/>
                            </gname>
                                <xsl:variable name="this" select="LocalityName" />
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('kLocalityName', $this)" >
                                    <BusStopDetails>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="CommonName"/>
                                    </BusStopDetails>

                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </BusStopGroup>
                        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate:

```
<BusStopGroup>
    <gname>Aberdeen</gname>
    <BusStopDetails>Union Square Bus Station</BusStopDetails>
    <BusStopDetails>Aberdeen Railway Station</BusStopDetails>
    <BusStopDetails>Aberdeen Ferry Terminal</BusStopDetails>
</BusStopGroup>
```

Update 2 now with html:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key  name="kLocalityName" match="BusStopDetails" use="LocalityName"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <html>
          <body>
            <h2>BusStops</h2>
            <table border="1">
              <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Locality</th>
                <th>BusStop</th>
                <th> Co-ordinates </th>
              </tr>
                    <!--for-each select="BusStops/BusStopDetails" group >-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="BusStopDetails[generate-id() = 
                                                                        generate-id(key('kLocalityName', LocalityName)[1])]"  >

                        <xsl:sort select="LocalityName"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="this" select="LocalityName" />
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('kLocalityName', $this)" >
                              <tr> 
                                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                  <td rowspan="{count(key('kLocalityName', $this))}"> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="LocalityName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="ParentLocalityName"/>) </td>
                                </xsl:if>                                      
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="CommonName"/></td>
                                <td>
                                     <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;q={Latitude},{Longitude}&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=14">
                                     (<xsl:value-of select="Latitude"/>) , (<xsl:value-of select="Longitude"/>)
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yeah i was trying to attempt something like this but i didnt know how to implement it into the stylesheet. Could you maybe show me an example please within the stylesheet?